# website using jquery form version 4.2.2 and jquery 3.1.2

Tags: jquery

I have problem with my form, because is doesn't work when submit the form, they take this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined.
```

My form code is:

```html
<form id="myFormxy" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="buscar_empresas.php?get=1" class="form-inline" method="post" role="form" >
        
        <div class="form-group mx-sm-3">
    <input name="razon_social" type="text" style="font-size: 12px;" class="form-control" id="razon_social" required placeholder="Nombre Empresa" />
    <input name="id_emp" type="hidden" id="id_emp" value="<?php echo $row_nombreh['id_emp']; ?>" />
  </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" style="font-size: 12px;" id="submit">Buscar</button>
        
        </form>
```

My javascript code is:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.2.2/jquery.form.min.js" integrity="sha384-FzT3vTVGXqf7wRfy8k4BiyzvbNfeYjK+frTVqZeNDFl8woCbF0CYG6g2fMEFFo/i" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 
        // esperamos que el DOM cargue
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // definimos las opciones del plugin AJAX FORM
   
   var opciones= {
                               beforeSubmit: mostrarLoader, //funcion que se ejecuta antes de enviar el form
                               success: mostrarRespuesta //funcion que se ejecuta una vez enviado el formulario
            };
             //asignamos el plugin ajaxForm al formulario myForm y le pasamos las opciones
            $('#myFormxy').ajaxForm(opciones); 
 
             //lugar donde defino las funciones que utilizo dentro de "opciones"
             function mostrarLoader(){
        $("#ajax_loadery").empty();
        $("#loader_gify").fadeIn("slow"); //muestro el loader de ajax
             };
             function mostrarRespuesta (responseText){
                          // alert("Mensaje enviado: "+responseText);  //responseText es lo que devuelve la página contacto.php. Si en contacto.php hacemos echo "Hola" , la variable responseText = "Hola" . Aca hago un alert con el valor de response text
        $("#ajax_loadery").fadeIn("fast");
        $("#loader_gify").fadeOut("fast"); // Hago desaparecer el loader de ajax
                          $("#ajax_loadery").html(responseText); // Aca utilizo la función append de JQuery para añadir el responseText  dentro del div "ajax_loader"
        if(responseText != "debes ingresar todos los datos") {
        $('#myFormxy').resetForm();
        }
             };
 
        }); 
 
</script>
```

Please I need help!! thanks

Comment: jQuery v3 introduces a lot of sweeping chances: one of which is the removal of the `jqXHR.success()` callback (it has been deprecated since v1.8, but many authors don't seem to bother to migrate/update). The plugin is obviously not updated to listen to resolution of promise using the `jqXHR.done()` callback. Your best best is to revert to jQuery v2 or lower.